# Open a jquery modal dialog on the left side of the window

Tags: jquery, dialog, position

I am using a jquery modal dialog, and I need to be able to position it on the left hand side of the page, but my code isn't working to set the position. What am I doing wrong?

```
var $dialog;
function dialog(url) {
    $.get(url, {}, function (html) {
        $dialog = $('<div id="dialog" title="Create New Case"></div>').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                $("#dialog").remove();
            }
        });
        $dialog.html(html);
        $dialog.dialog("option", "width", "auto");
        $dialog.dialog("option", "height", "auto");
        $dialog.dialog("option", "left", "1%");
        $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because jQueryUI dialogs have no option named `left`.

Use the `position` option instead [as indicated in the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position).

Note that you will have to set the position after opening the dialog or you will see some unusual results as jQueryUI's position functionality does not support positioning hidden elements.

Comment: I changed it to $dialog.dialog("option", "position", { my: "left", at: "left" }); and it's still breaking. Is there a reason?

Comment: You may need to add an `of` element to your position object.

Comment: I need to it be on the left side of the page. The documentation you sent me has of:button what do I do to make it just the page?

Comment: Works for me without the `of` being specified. [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/winterblood/Qjq5q/) showing it working.

Comment: [And an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/winterblood/Qjq5q/3/) showing switching between centered and left aligned.

Comment: It still isn't working on my code. I have jquery ui-1.8.1 do I need 1.9.1 to make it work?

Comment: The position utility was introduced in 1.8 (according to the jQueryUI documentation) so it should be fine. Beyond that I can't really see what could be going wrong without updated code to test.